# Alkalis and Bases

Tags: acid-base, terminology

I just learned about acids and bases during class. I noticed that my textbook mentions the term "alkali/alkaline" and sometimes it mentions "base/basic". As far as I know, alkalis and bases are metal oxides hydroxides. But why does my textbook make use of *two* words that mean the same thing instead of just *one* of them? Do these terms (alkali and base) mean something different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These words are in many cases interchangeably used: an *alkaline* solution/compound is the same as a *basic* solution/compound.

But you can specify "alkali" to refer to those bases that are soluble in water and that are salts of alkaline or alkaline earth metals too.

Alkali is like a subset of bases which fulfills these conditions.

E.g.:

- Sodium hydroxide is a base, and also is an alkali metal salt, and is also soluble in water, so it is also an alkali.
- Ammonia is a base, soluble in water, but not a salt, so it is not an alkali.
- Magnesium hydroxide is a base, is a salt of an alkaline earth metal, but it is not soluble in water, so it is not an alkali.

Answer (score 2):

I think an alkali is a substance that *dissolves in water* to produce $\ce{OH- (aq)}$ ions. Since the $\ce{OH- (aq)}$ ions can react with acids, that makes alkalis bases as well. Therefore alkalis are *soluble* bases. 
Ammonia can also dissolve in water to form ammonium, $\ce{NH4+ (aq)}$ ions and $\ce{OH- (aq)}$, that is, it undergoes hydrolysis, in which case hydroxyl, $\ce{OH- (aq)}$ ions are produced. Therefore in that respect ammonia qualifies as an alkali, and we have to remember the very high solubility of ammonia in water as demonstrated in the *fountain experiment*.
Sodium carbonate is an alkali because it also dissolves in water to form hydroxyl ions.
Therefore, from this summary there are two very important criteria for  compounds to be considered an alkali:

1. It must dissolve in water
2. It must produce $\ce{OH- (aq)}$ ions in the aqueous medium.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please also have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.